# javascript multiple groups select all

Tags: javascript, django

i'm new to javascript and I have the following javascript function called selectallrep.js:

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('report_id');
  for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to get the element name 'report_id' which is part of my django form.  There are several groups of report_id's which have separate for loops.  The current method is selecting everything in the django form below:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <script src= "{% static '/search/selectallrep.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
          {% if fingrouplist is not None %}
                      <h4><strong>Financial</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                              <ul>
                              {% for app in fingrouplist %}
                              <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                              {% endfor %}
                              </ul>
          {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class = "row">
          {% if cagrouplist is not None %}
                          <h4><strong>Care Assure</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>


                                  <ul>
                                  {% for app in cagrouplist %}
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  </ul>
          {% endif %}
                          </div>

                        <div class = "row">
          {% if pigrouplist is not None %}
          <h4><strong>Performance Improvement</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                  <ul>
                                  {% for app in pigrouplist %}
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  </ul>
          {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class = "row">
          {% if scgrouplist is not None %}
                          <h4><strong>Supply Chain</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                  <ul>
                                  {% for app in scgrouplist %}
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  </ul>
          {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class = "row">
          {% if dssgrouplist is not None %}
                          <h4><strong>DSS Monitoring</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                  <ul>
                                  {% for app in dssgrouplist %}
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  </ul>
          {% endif %}
                        </div>

                        <div class = "row">
          {% if othgrouplist is not None %}
                          <h4><strong>Other</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                  <ul>
                                  {% for app in othgrouplist %}
                                  <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                  {% endfor %}
                                  </ul>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class = "row">
          {% if bhgrouplist is not None %}
                        <h4><strong>Behavioral Health</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                <ul>
                                {% for app in bhgrouplist %}
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
        {% endif %}
</div>
                        <div class="row">
        {% if cegrouplist is not None %}
        <h4><strong>Clinical Excellence</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                <ul>
                                {% for app in cegrouplist %}
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
        {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
        {% if psggrouplist is not None %}
          <h4><strong>Physician Service Group</strong/></br></br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Select All</h4>

                                <ul>
                                {% for app in psggrouplist %}
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

I understand it's because they all have the same element id, but what do I need to do to make each Select All only part of that group?  Every example i've found online shows using a table class.  Unfortunately I don't have a table i'm using divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing any of your html markup, the following method should suffice

```
function toggle(source) {
    var els = source.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[name=report_id]');    
    if (els && els.length>0) {
        for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
            els[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

There are other, jQuery ways to do this, by using `parentsUntil('.row')`, etc. But this is the most straight forward way

Comment: Could you help explain to me what the function is doing?

Comment: @user1470034 basically I am making use of the `querySelectorAll` element method, have a read up here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: @user1470034 So, from the source element, we are traversing upwards, out of the `<h4 />` tag, and hitting the parent `<div />` tag, from that element, we then search for all `input` tags (within the contextual div) having the name of `report_id`. That gets me the list of inputs for further iteration/checked assignment.